# Conditionally Not Pass Named Arguments in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a more "pythonic" way to write something like this:

```
import good as G

def make_schema(schema, allow_extra_keys=False):
    if allow_extra_keys is True:
        return G.Schema(schema, extra_keys=G.Allow)
    else:
        return G.Schema(schema)
```

where if `allow_extra_keys` is True, we pass the `extra_keys` named arg into `G.Schema`, otherwise, we don't.

It seems a bit redundant to have to write `G.Schema()` twice. 
Is there a way to write it such that we only return `G.Schema()` once, or is the above the conventional way for how things should be written in Python?

Comment: At first you could remove the `is True`.

Comment: +1 to Klaus -- pythonic does not mean "fewer lines". Just drop the `is True`. Anything more and you lose readability (which is literally a core part of "pythonic").

Answer (score 0):

What about this one-liner if/else?

```
return G.Schema(schema, extra_keys=G.Allow) if allow_extra_keys else G.Schema(schema)
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same code, just rearranged and less readable.

Comment: Agreed, but OP is asking to have only one return statement. I disagree that this is less readable. This is perfectly readable and pythonic to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`import good as G
 def make_schema(schema, allow_extra_keys=False):
     return G.Schema(schema, extra_keys=G.Allow if allow_extra_keys else None)`

Comment: That code doesn't necessary do the same as the original. That would only be the case if the default value for the `extra_keys` parameter in `G.schema()` is `None`.

Comment: agreed with slashCoder -- If extra_keys is indeed None by default this works -- but if somebody were to change the default value in a later release of the Schema class, then this would magically break.

Comment: Point taken ! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
import good as G

def make_schema(schema, allow_extra_keys=False):
    kwargs = {'extra_keys': G.Allow} if allow_extra_keys else {}
    return G.Schema(schema, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I was considering this, but I think the basic if/else in the problem statement is simpler than introducing kwargs. Although I admittedly use this style in my own code

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to find out what's the default value of the `extra_keys` parameter in `G.Schema()` (either from looking into the source code or documentation) and then set what you'll pass to either that or `G.Allow` depending on the value of `allow_extra_keys`. Still needs an `if`, but at least you only have one call to `G.Schema` and no messy kwargs handling.

Let's say the defaul is `G.Deny` then you do:

```
def make_schema(schema, allow_extra_keys=False):
    extra_keys = G.Allow if allow_extra_keys else G.Deny
    return G.Schema(schema, extra_keys)
```